# When + and - rep changes cancel out, the icon disappears in the Stack Exchange dropdown

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, top-bar

I have `+40+50+5 = +55` and `-50-1-1-1-2 = -55`, so I have an overall change of 0:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

However, I think the dropdown should show +0 next to the ubuntu icon - it looks like I have no rep changes on Ask Ubuntu, but I actually do have changes.

Comment: Personally, I would like it to show **+50 / -50 instead of +0**. It's still common for me to see a +9 up there and waste a minute wondering what SE action gives you exactly 9 rep before remembering I downvoted something earlier; +10 / -1 would save me that nuisance.

Comment: @Ixrec I see your point, but there is the breakdown on your profile and in the dropdown...

Comment: I would prefer if it showed only the positive rep change, after all it is called *acheivements*.  The negative rep change could be shown only when you click the drop down menu.

Comment: @lxrec I think it should use the ± (plus-minus) sign with 0 after it (±0), meaning you gained neither more or less but something actually happened with it.